# useNativeDriver with PanResponder

Tags: react-native

I was trying to move all things that I could to `useNativeDriver`. I tried this:

```
onPanResponderMove: Animated.event([null, { dy:this.state.appearAnim }], { useNativeDriver:true }),
```

However this causes the error of:

> config.onPanResponderMove is not a function

If I just set `useNativeDriver` to `false`, it works as per expectations.
Does anyone have any idea on how to use native driver with PanResponder?

Answer (score 12):

I quote from the react-native github repository:

#### [PanResponder can't work with Animated.event([], {useNativeDriver: true});](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13377)

> This is a current limitation of native Animated.event. It doesn't work with PanResponder because it is implemented in JavaScript. You can have a look at https://github.com/wix/react-native-interactable which can handle gestures with native animated values.

Looks like it is currently not possible to useNativeDriver with the PanResponder in react native.

Comment: Also we can use native tracking since 0.55 now - https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-releases/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#055 - https://twitter.com/kzzzf/status/958362032650244101/video/1