# React Native Error: "Animated.event now requires a second argument for options"

Tags: react-native, animation

Does anyone know why the following error appears when I run the below code?

Error reported by React Native Expo in the command line:

```
Animated.event now requires a second argument for options
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LogBox/LogBox.js:117:10 in registerWarning
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LogBox/LogBox.js:63:8 in warnImpl
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LogBox/LogBox.js:36:4 in console.warn
- node_modules/expo/build/environment/react-native-logs.fx.js:18:4 in warn
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Animated/src/AnimatedEvent.js:141:6 in constructor 
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Animated/src/AnimatedImplementation.js:520:24 in event
* src/screens/ImageScreen.js:21:24 in ImageScreen
```

... a lot more of the same output for many lines ... I can post the full output if people think it's needed.

This is the code - it's not complicated:

```
import React, {useState, useRef} from 'react';
import { Animated, PanResponder, View, Image, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const style = StyleSheet.create({
  mainView: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    backgroundColor: "red"
  },  
  moviePoster_posterStyle: {
    resizeMode: "cover"
  }
});

const ImageScreen = () => {

  const pan = useRef(new Animated.ValueXY()).current;

  const panResponder = useRef(
    PanResponder.create({
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
      onPanResponderGrant: () => {
        pan.setOffset({
          x: pan.x._value,
          y: pan.y._value
        });
      },
      onPanResponderMove: Animated.event(
        [
          null,
          { dx: pan.x, dy: pan.y }
        ]
      ),
      onPanResponderRelease: () => {
        pan.flattenOffset();
      }
    })
  ).current;

    return (
      <View style={style.mainView}
        onStartShouldSetResponderCapture={() => {return false}}>
        <Animated.View
          style={{
            transform: [{ translateX: pan.x }, { translateY: pan.y }]
          }}
          {...panResponder.panHandlers}
        >
          <Image
              style={style.moviePoster_posterStyle}
              source={require("../../assets/This_Gun_for_Hire_(1942)_poster.jpg")}
          />
        </Animated.View>
      </View>
    )


};

export default ImageScreen;
```

Thank you!

Comment: If my answer helped you, please upvote it! or mark as accepted answer! Thank you too!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

As said [here](https://github.com/nysamnang/react-native-raw-bottom-sheet/issues/81), you need to specify `useNativeDriver` on your code (Set it to true or false, depending on your use)

Your code should now look like this:

```js
import React, {useState, useRef} from 'react';
import { Animated, PanResponder, View, Image, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const style = StyleSheet.create({
  mainView: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    backgroundColor: "red"
  },  
  moviePoster_posterStyle: {
    resizeMode: "cover"
  }
});

const ImageScreen = () => {

  const pan = useRef(new Animated.ValueXY()).current;

  const panResponder = useRef(
    PanResponder.create({
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
      onPanResponderGrant: () => {
        pan.setOffset({
          x: pan.x._value,
          y: pan.y._value
        });
      },
      onPanResponderMove: Animated.event(
        [
          null,
          { dx: pan.x, dy: pan.y }
        ],
        {useNativeDriver: false}
      ),
      onPanResponderRelease: () => {
        pan.flattenOffset();
      }
    })
  ).current;

    return (
      <View style={style.mainView}
        onStartShouldSetResponderCapture={() => {return false}}>
        <Animated.View
          style={{
            transform: [{ translateX: pan.x }, { translateY: pan.y }]
          }}
          {...panResponder.panHandlers}
        >
          <Image
              style={style.moviePoster_posterStyle}
              source={require("../../assets/This_Gun_for_Hire_(1942)_poster.jpg")}
          />
        </Animated.View>
      </View>
    )


};

export default ImageScreen;
```

Being the only difference here:

```js
onPanResponderMove: Animated.event(
  [
    null,
    { dx: pan.x, dy: pan.y }
  ],
  {useNativeDriver: false}
),
```

Comment: Yeah, i'm going to change the answer to make it work. Looks like it onPanResponderMove doesn't work with useNativeDriver

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45363416/usenativedriver-with-panresponder?rq=1

Comment: can you see this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75246881/style-not-perfect-on-scroller-view-in-react-native

Answer (score 5):

This is what I did to fix, As from [github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13377) repository, it seems PanResponder can't work with Animated.event([], {useNativeDriver: true});

---

So I twisted a little bit changing useNativeDriver to false on both just for removing errors.

```
const panResponder = PanResponder.create({
    onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
    onPanResponderMove: Animated.event(
      [
        null,
        {
          dx: pan.x, // x,y are Animated.Value
          dy: pan.y,
        },
      ],
      { useNativeDriver: false }
    ),
    onPanResponderRelease: () => {
      Animated.spring(
        pan, // Auto-multiplexed
        { toValue: { x: 0, y: 0 }, useNativeDriver: false }

        // Back to zero
      ).start();
    },
  });
```

---

Code is extracted from [Expo Documentations](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/react-native/animatedvaluexy/)

---

This will remove both errors :

1. Animated.event now requires a second argument for options
2. config.onPanResponderMove is not a function

---

List item

Answer (score 0):

add `{ useNativeDriver: false }` in  `Animated.event` and then restart app. I fixed.
Example:

```
 const panResponder = useRef(
    PanResponder.create({
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
      onPanResponderMove: Animated.event([null, {dx: pan.x, dy: pan.y}], {
        useNativeDriver: false,
      }),
      onPanResponderRelease: () => {
        Animated.spring(pan, {
          toValue: {x: 0, y: 0},
          useNativeDriver: true,
        }).start();
      },
    }),
  ).current;
```